# Django: import CSV but prevent existing duplicates

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, csv, import

I have a simple Django/sqlite application that is importing a CSV with N rows of transactions.
A Transaction has the following fields:
`date`, `description`, `amount`.

When I import these I want to ignore any that already exist. This can be easily accomplished with some constraints at the database level.

However, I *do* want to allow duplicates within the same import. e.g., I make two transactions on the same day for the same thing.

I'm trying to avoid looking up each transaction as I read the CSV...

I suppose I could query all transactions between the first and last dates of the CSV and search this result set as I iterate through the new transactions.

Hoping for a nicer solution.

Comment: Import to staging table and then move to final table from there.

Answer (score 0):

With a DB constraint you can't do it. Either you can store a duplicate date+description+amount, or it will prevent the duplicate from ever being stored by raising an IntegrityError

What I think you need to do, is have an import-dataset-ID, or if possible import a transaction ID from the data source. Then disallow duplicates of all four fields.

Alternatively, have an exceptions file, where the CSV data that is a duplicate gets saved, for subsequent (possibly manual) checking as to whether it is or isn't a duplicate. But you still won't be able to store it as a duplicate. You'll have to "lie" by altering its description. Maybe append "#2 ok-by ABC"
to identify who allowed it through.

```
for row in csvreader:
    new = MyObj(
       # put data from row into a new Django object
       )
    try:
        new.save()
    except IntegerityError:
        csvwriter.writerow( row)   # store the exception
```